# Neo4j javascript - Session.run() - how to run multiple query in session

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I am using neo4j javascript driver. I am able to run a single query. But I can't able to create multiple nodes with properties. Can anyone tell me how to do?

```
  session
        .run('CREATE (fit1:fitproto {title:"Relaince Industries",name:"Rajni",country:"India",email:"rajni@gmail.com"}),(fit2:fitproto {title:"State Bank of India",name:"Rajni",country:"India",email:"rajni@gmail.com"}) RETURN(fitproto)')
        .subscribe({
            onNext: function (record) {

                const node = record.get(1);

                console.log(node);
                record.forEach(function (res) {
                    console.log(res.Node);
                });

                res.send(record.get(0));


            },
            onCompleted: function () {
                session.close();
            },
            onError: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an array of properties for new nodes through parameters. [Then `UNWIND` it, create a node and `SET` properties](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/#cypher-parameters-create-multiple-nodes-with-properties):

```
session
    .run(` 
      UNWIND $propsArray as props
      CREATE (fit:fitproto) SET fit = props 
      RETURN fit
    `, {
        propsArray: [{
                title: "Relaince Industries",
                name: "Rajni",
                country: "India",
                email: "rajni@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                title: "State Bank of India",
                name: "Rajni",
                country: "India",
                email: "rajni@gmail.com"
            }
        ]
    })
    .subscribe({
        onNext: function(record) {
            console.log(record.get('fit'));
        },
        onCompleted: function() {
            session.close();
        },
        onError: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: @stdob-- consider the same example .need update query using post request when a user changes some of the data (will pass a JSON to the post method) how to do it?

Comment: @ramyakrishna I think this is a completely new question, so you should open a new topic with details.

Comment: @stdob--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586299/neo4j-update-query-using-post-method check this link